# How to slice pandas.MultiIndex at generic level l?

Tags: python, pandas

`df.xs(i, level=l)` gets the values of index i at level l, but does not allow to set them.

The following sets the values of index i at level 2 [(cf. documentation)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-mi-slicers):

```
df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[:,:,i],:] = 0
```

Is there a way to set the values of index i at level l (for ANY level l)? I need this because I do not know ex ante what level I need to operate on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need `pd.index.get_level_values`

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,50,(100,8))).set_index(list(range(5)))

i = 7

l = 2
df.loc[df.index.get_level_values(l) == i]
#               5   6   7
#0  1  2 3  4            
#15 12 7 36 24  6  48  41

l = 4
df.loc[df.index.get_level_values(l) == i]
#                5  6   7
#0  1  2  3  4           
#22 31 21 32 7  33  8  14
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this is precisely what I needed! Am I correct in assuming that `df.index.get_level_values(l)==i` is guaranteed to still be an index on `df`? I.e. the order is maintained?

Comment: @user449277 `df.index.get_level_values(l)==i` will give you an unindexed Boolean array that is the same length of your `DataFrame` So when using `.loc` with that, it will subset to only the rows where level `l` of the index takes on the value `i`

Comment: if you needed that to be a True/False Series with the original `DataFrame` index, you could do something like `pd.Series(df.index.get_level_values(l)==i, index=df.index)`, or just assign it as a column to the original `df`